# Converting string to double with no manipulation

Tags: c++

New to C++ so bear with me. I'm trying to convert a string that I'm bringing in from a file. When I use stod, or stringstream to convert the string to whatever, the problem I'm having is that these methods are cleaning up the string in order to turn it into it's double equivalent. For example, "43.r" is converted to "43.00". Seems like a nice feature but I need to know if the data is imperfect in any way.
 
I need a way to turn a string into a double without ANY changing of the data. If the string cannot be *directly* converted to a double, throw an exception. I'm struggling to find a way to do this without writing my own conversion method which I'm not really confident enough to do yet.

Comment: There are very few things that can be done entirely by calling a function from the C++ library that does it. More often than not you must implement the overall logic by yourself, and only using the functions and the resourcesin the C++ library to do specific sub-tasks. In this case, you'll want to use `std::from_chars`, and then validate the results to verify that it processed the entire string, in addition to the error indication from `std::from_chars` itself. Are you familiar with `std::from_chars`? Or, in case of earlier C++ standard, `std::istringstream`, `>>`, and some additional logic.

Comment: The functions you mentioned don't do any manipulation or guessing. They simply stop parsing when they reach the end of the number. `43.` is a valid floating point number. `std::stod` has an additional argument that lets you check where it stopped parsing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof